# Insertion Sort Double Array with User Input - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, double, reverse, insertion-sort

I am tasked with making a double (or float) array in descending order with user input, using a sorting method such as insertion sort.

I've tried manipulating the number values throughout the code. It keeps throwing "Index -1 out of bounds for length 50"

```
public static void main(String args[])
   {
       int size, i, j;
    Double temp;
       Double arr[] = new Double[50];
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter Number of Elements : ");
       size = scan.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Enter the Elements : ");
       for(i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
           arr[i] = scan.nextDouble();
       }
       for(i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
           temp = arr[i];
           j = i - 1;
           while((temp <= arr[j]) && (j >= 0))
           {
               arr[j+1] = arr[j];
               j = j - 1;
           }
           arr[j+1] = temp;
       }
       System.out.print("Elements Sorted : \n");
       for(i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
           System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should include a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: Yes of course! I fixed that.

Comment: It works and I understand why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
j = i - 1;
while((temp <= arr[j]) && (j >= 0))
```

The problem is that you don't check sure `j >= 0` before you try to use it to access an element of `arr` so that on the very first run through the loop you are accessing `arr[-1]`, hence the error.

In most languages with expression like `expr1 && expr2`, expr2 will not be evaluated if expr1 qualifies as false.

The correct code would look like:

```
j = i - 1;
while((j >= 0) && (temp <= arr[j]))
```